# Why are some data types Deprecated while others Obsolete?

Tags: programming-languages, terminology

Why are some data types or functions made Obsolete in a newer version of an API and others are marked as Deprecated? Why not make them all Obsolete or why not make them all Deprecated?

Comment: Are you talking about deprecation?

Comment: Ya, but the difference is that Deprecated data types and functions can be used although with warnings but the Obsolete are completely erased off.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: What? Which programming language?

Comment: Take SNMP for example. You may find a lot of things Obsolete and some others Deprecated.

Comment: The difference between obsolete/deprecated/whatever depends on the programming language or the framework. Each has its standards. Why not ask them for your particular case?

Comment: Why does this question have negative votes? Its better than many questions that people scream to give upvotes. Granted, the OP's English is poor, but it is clear enough to get the point.

Comment: thanx for your support @ThomasEding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deprecation typically serves as a warning that a feature is no longer in favor with the designers of the language. The reasoning for this is one of reverse compatibility. It gives the users of a language time to adjust their code before the language drops those features. It can also serve as a migration path to a new version of a given feature. The feature in question might be retrofitted at some point in the future or rendered obsolete and removed.

Comment: `The feature in question might be retrofitted at some point in the future or rendered obsolete and removed.` This makes it sounds like the main difference is that something marked as `Obsolete` is a potential candidate for being removed in future versions, and `Deprecated` is the step before `Obsolete`.

Comment: It's going to depend on the language or framework in question. The terms are somewhat...flexible... in my experience.